# In NestJS, how do I build a guard that verifies if the user's email is confirmed?

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js, guard

I'm using NestJS 10.  I would like to create a guard that protects an endpoint, not only if the user is logged in, but also if they have confirmed their email.  I'm using NestJS/passport, and create JWT tokens like so

```
  async getTokens(userId: string, username: string) {
    const [accessToken, refreshToken] = await Promise.all([
      this.jwtService.signAsync(
        {
          sub: userId,
          username,
        },
        {
          secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_ACCESS_SECRET'),
          expiresIn: ACCESS_TOKEN_DURATION,
        },
      ),
      this.jwtService.signAsync(
        {
          sub: userId,
          username,
        },
        {
          secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_REFRESH_SECRET'),
          expiresIn: REFRESH_TOKEN_DURATION,
        },
      ),
    ]);

    return {
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
    };
  }
```

I have this AccessTokenStrategy configured in my auth module ...

```
type JwtPayload = {
  sub: string;
  username: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class AccessTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor() {
    console.log("access token strategy ...");
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_ACCESS_SECRET,
    });
  }

  validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to guard my email confirm guard.  My user entity has a boolean "isEmailConfirmed" attribute but I'm not quite sure how to add/extract that from the payload if I am to build such a guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide your database engine, so I'm going to assume it is Prisma, although it isn't that important here.

You could create a guard as follows:

```
import { Injectable, type CanActivate, type ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

import { DbUserService } from '@/modules/database/user.service';

interface GuardRequest {
    readonly userId: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class IsEmailConfirmedGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private readonly dbUserService: DbUserService) {}

    public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<GuardRequest>();
        const user = request.userId;

        const isEmailConfirmed = await this.dbUserService.isEmailConfirmed(
            userId,
        );

        return isEmailConfirmed;
    }
}
```

Of course `isEmailConfirmed` function should query your database for the `isEmailConfirmed` attribute value of the user in accordance to the `userId`, let's say.

Then you apply the guard to your endpoint controller:

```
import { Body, Controller, HttpCode, HttpStatus, Param, Patch, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';

import { IsEmailConfirmedGuard } from '@/guards/is-email-confirmed.guard';

import Routes from './example.routes';

@Controller(Routes.EXAMPLE_CONTROLLER)
export class ExampleController {
    @UseGuards(IsEmailConfirmedGuard)
    @Patch(Routes.EXAMPLE)
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    public async example(
    ): Promise<void> {
       return;
    }
}
```